# PHP: How to replace values in a string sequentially?

Tags: php, string

I'm currently using PHP's str_replace to replace a particular value with another, in a loop.

The problem is, str_replace will replace ALL of the instances of the first value, with the second value, rather than replacing them sequentially.  For example:

```
$replacements = array('A', 'one', 'some');
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and runs to the forest.";
foreach($replacements as $replace){
    $str = str_replace('the', $replace, $str);
}
```

this will ultimately return:

"A quick brown fox jumps over A lazy dog and runs to A forest."

rather than what I want which would be:

"A quick brown fox jumps over one lazy dog and runs to some forest."

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?  I thought I could use preg_replace but I'm mediocre with regex.

Comment: Similar but definitely not duplicates... that one wants to limit to only one replace total, I want to do a sequential replace of each instance of needle, with a different replacement value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Untested, but I think this will do the trick.

```
$replacements = array('A', 'one', 'some');
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and runs to the forest.";
foreach($replacements as $replace){
    $str = preg_replace('/the/i', $replace, $str, 1);
}
echo $str;
```

Edit: added the i to make it case insensitive

Comment: +1.  Works when I run it here: http://codepad.org/Sxpksp0A -- I suppose a more efficient method might be to use a single call to preg_replace_callback()...

Comment: hmmm works on codepad but not working for me in production.  Here is my real line of code: `$to_parse = preg_replace('/{{'.$words.'}}/i', $output, $to_parse, 1);` I'm replacing a series of tokens in the format {{value}}, does the pattern need tweaking to find that?  I tried escaping the braces but it didn't seem to help...

Comment: Here is a stripped down version of my production code on codepad... what's odd is the initial preg_match_all is throwing an error when that part works fine for me in production.  http://codepad.org/zxhRKLUx

Comment: Get it working with a static test string and no curly braces first. Then add your curly braces and get that working. Then add your $words variable.

Comment: I think you need to escape the | characters when you use them in your pattern. I made untested adjustments here: http://codepad.org/XMgUJeZO

Comment: Hmmmm that looks good, but I get no output when I run it on codepad... what am I missing?

Comment: I think codepad is having problems with preg_match_all. I tested and I'm getting flawless results on my machine.

Comment: Aha!  You are correct, codepad doesn't like preg_match_all.  Works great in production, looks like it was escaping the | as you said.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay maybe this is super convoluted?

```
$replacements = array('A', 'one', 'some');
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and runs to the forest.";
$str_array = explode(" ", $str);
$replace_word = "the";
$i = $j = 0;
foreach($str_array as $word){
      if(strtolower($word) === $replace_word){
         $str_array[$i] = $new_word[$j];
         $j++;
      }
   $i++;
}
$str = implode(" ", $str_array);
```

Comment: Yes I just noticed that typo actually but SE won't allow me to edit it.  In my production code, that mistake is not present.

Comment: Yeah that's very similar to the approach I took to work around this... I just figured there HAD to be a better way than blowing up multiple paragraphs of content into individual words and doing a comparison on every word.

Answer (score -2):

Apparantly this seemed to work :

```
$replacements = array('A', 'one', 'some');
$the=array('the','the','the');
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog and runs to the forest.";
$str = str_ireplace($the, $replacements, $str);
```

I think this is exactly what was asked.

see parameter description http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

http://codepad.org/VIacFmoM

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the 'count' feature of str_replace!  Unfortunately it does not appear to be doing anything at all.  There is no change to my results.  Additionally when I use an integer for the number rather than a variable, I get `Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference`

Comment: The "count" parameter is a reference to a variable in which `str_replace()` will _write_ the number of replacements made. It has nothing to do with what the OP asked.

Comment: aha, that explains why it didn't seem to do what I thought it would, based on the suggestion to use it!

Comment: That's not how the $count parameter works. You supply a variable for $count, and after the operation is performed $count will tell you how many replacements were made.

Comment: I edited my answer, we need not go through a loop when we have array of search elements and another array of replace elements, the function does it itself.

Comment: @Anzz, consider *testing* the code you write before posting it if you don't know if it will work or not. Your edit can't work, for the exact same reason the OP asked the question.

Comment: @Radu  http://codepad.org/VIacFmoM  have a look at this. I must have changed the $str=  before copying the link

Comment: @Anzz, as you can see in your own codepad link, the code outputs exactly what the OP says he *doesn't* want to output.